# passing sql row result as key in url

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to pass a sql row result as a key into an url.

I am getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in

with my php line :

```
 echo "<td>" . "<a href=\"viewDetails.php?"."$row['title']"."\>Betterdisplay</a>" . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a small error in your string concatenation

```
echo "<td>" . "<a href=\"viewDetails.php?".$row['title']."\">Betterdisplay</a>" . "</td>";
```

Comment: thanks that worked!